# How to unlock a Samung Galaxy S5 locked with a pattern on a broken screen

Tags: lock-screens, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 that has a shattered screen. It doesn't unlock, but the phone works fine.

I purchased a new phone, and I want to transfer all my contents from the old phone to the new phone.

The problem is the phone is locked with a pattern, and I cannot accesses it as the screen is broken. Does anyone know how to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your new Device is also Android (you have not given the make and Operating system of your phone),The most probable solution for you is Samsung Smart Switch  regarding the transfer of contents from the older devices(any os like Mac or Android) to a new Android device.

Check this [site](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/smartswitch/)for more info.